# ajax cannot pass datastring to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, string

I can't receive the data value on my php script, the ajax success fires but the data on my database is not changed when I send this.

```
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "database/clientpanel/agent_panel/notiffolder/notifedit.php",
        data: {
        email: email,
        number: number,
        emailon: emailon,
        texton: texton,
        email_delay: emaildel,
        ext_delay: textdel,
        timezone1: zone1,
        timezone2: zone2
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#upnotif").show();
            $("#errnotif").hide();
            $("#errnotif1").hide();
            $("#errnotif2").hide();
        }
    });
```

php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../../../dbinfo.inc.php");

$query=" select * from tele_panel_notification where client='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['clientid'])."'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$client = $row['client'];

if($client == ""){
$query = "insert into tele_panel_notification set
emailon = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['emailon'])."',
texton = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['texton'])."',
timezone = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['timezone'])."',
timezone2 = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['timezone2'])."',
email = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',
email_delay = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email_delay'])."',
text_delay = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['text_delay'])."',
number = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['number'])."',
client='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['clientid'])."'";

    //execute the query
    if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
        //if saving success
        echo "true";
    }else{
        //if unable to create new record
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
}
else{
$query = "UPDATE tele_panel_note SET 
emailon = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['emailon'])."',
texton = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['texton'])."',
timezone = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['timezone'])."',
timezone2 = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['timezone2'])."',
email = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."',
email_delay = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email_delay'])."',
text_delay = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['text_delay'])."',
number = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['number'])."'
where client='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['clientid'])."'";

    //execute the query
    if( $mysqli->query($query) ) {
        //if saving success
        echo "true";
    }else{
        //if unable to create new record
        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }
}   

    //close database connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Check the URL of the ajax, and also on the top of your code on the php, try to input first something like this echo "test"; die; and try to check it on firebug if you're using Firefox or on your console(Chrome,IE) if it outputs "test", if there's no output, then there's something wrong with your URL

Comment: Did you check if the data arrives successfully to the php page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your PHP part,

```
   $result = $mysqli->query($query);
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $client = $row['client'];

   if($client == ""){
```

You should verify directly with your row if you want to be able to know if the row already exists:

```
   $result = $mysqli->query($query);
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   //$client = $row['client'];

   if(!$row){
```

And then your client variable is useless.